# Android Launcher getting crash after restart mobile

Tags: android, launcher

I have created a luncher,and its functionalities are working good, but when i restart my mobile it is showing a message "unfortunately your luncher getting stop" like this.manifest is :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="small" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="xlarge" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="480"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<uses-feature
    android:exported="true"
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified|adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".config"
        android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".sosconfi"
        android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".clock_display"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_clock_display"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".about"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".boot_completed"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

and i have created a receiver,

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(serviceIntent);
    }


}
```

can any one give solution for it.

Comment: Application is getting crash when i restart mobile

Comment: are you getting log in your ide

Comment: After restart i am not getting Logs

Comment: it will not display you have to save it to file to view it...check [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/reading-logs-programatically)